# Ruby Axlsx true auto-width for columns?

Tags: ruby, excel, column-width, axlsx

I'm using Axlsx to create an Excel file with one worksheet. I cannot figure out how to get all of the column widths to automatically resize to fit all of the data. Consider the following code where I add rows to a worksheet `ws`:

```
  ws.add_row ["this is just a test to see how far it will go because column will not show", "test", "this is also a testtt"]
  ws.add_row [""]
```

By default, columns seem to use auto-width, but even if not, I tried adding the `:widths=>[:auto, :auto, :auto]` to my `add_row` code. It seems like some kind of auto fit is applied to my columns because that first long column is expanding to fit most of the cell. But it does not fit entire cell, just expands enough to fit most but leaves off the last word or two.

Any way to achieve a *true* autofit functionality?

Comment: Autofit is more of an application scaling event than an attribute of a column or row. What you can do is scale the column based on the size (length) of the largest value. Might have to mess around with padding and the like. We have struggled with this in the past and resorted to having the user perform this action rather than trying to handle it in process. Please note that auto scale is also dependent on zoom level in excel eg if you zoom out what used to fit in a cell no longer does because of its dependence on rendered font size inside a cell

Answer (score 0):

How about the next cord ?

```
wb = Axlsx::Package.new.workbook
wb.use_autowidth = true
wb.add_worksheet(name: 'sheet_name') do |sheet|
  ws.add_row ["this is just a test to see how far it will go because column will not show", "test", "this is also a testtt"]
end
```